# how to execute linux command in python which changes default prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to execute a python script with some commands which change linux prompt.

```
>>> import os
>>> import commands
>>> os.chdir("/home/mycmd")
>>> commands.getoutput("pkill mycmd")
''
>>> commands.getoutput("mycmd") # it was stuck, had to press contrl^c
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/commands.py", line 50, in getoutput
    return getstatusoutput(cmd)[1]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/commands.py", line 60, in getstatusoutput
    text = pipe.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Manually when I execute `mycmd`, I see `(shell)` prompt rather than `#` prompt. Looks like with commands.getoutput it is not supported, is there any way I can execute such commands with python script which change the prompt?

Comment: Does mycmd wait under any circumstances? Under those circumstances the command would never return as it would never finish executing

Comment: This has everything to do with what `mycmd` does, and that certainly isn't a standard command. Linux itself has very few prompts; what you're thinking of is likely part of your shell or some other REPL.

Comment: Once I execute `mycmd`, it enters into different prompt, and inside that, I can give some more commands which will change the prompt, and when I give `exit 3`, normal linux prompt will appear.

Comment: Well it is waiting for the process to write to the pipe as evidenced by you interrupting on text = pipe.read()

Comment: So `mycmd` is some sort of interactive program. When you run it in `getoutput`, its output is hidden (being collected into a string by your python script) and it still waited for your instructions.

Comment: Is there any other way to run it and handle different prompts other than os or commands module?

Comment: `commands` is utterly inappropriate for running a process that takes input. Look at the `subprocess` module for much better tools for dealing with processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using subprocess:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['pkill', 'mycmd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=stdout)
p.communicate()
```

> This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:

```
os.system
os.spawn*
os.popen*
popen2.*
commands.*
```

[subprocess - Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)